# Why don't my other tabs display when I add an accordion?

Tags: html

I've used code from W3Schools and all was fine until I added the code for 
the accordion. Now the other tabs no longer display.

The html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

div.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

div.tabcontent {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#London {background-color:green;}
#Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
#Paris {background-color:Red;}
#Oslo {background-color:orange;}

button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Subject 1</a>
  <a href="#">Subject 2</a>
  <a href="#">Subject 3</a>
  <a href="#">Subject 4</a>
</div>

<div id="main">

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>

<p><h2><b>Heading</p></h2></b>
<p>Intro text......
</p>

<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">One</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Two</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'red')">Three</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Four</button>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>One</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</P>

<button class="accordion">1.1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">1.2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">1.3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Two</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p> 
 </div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Three</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Four</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}



var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}

</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is false

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>One</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</P>
```

it should be that

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>One</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed enough divs after your accordion, you were one short

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    #main {
        transition: margin-left .5s;
        padding: 16px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    .tablink {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 17px;
        width: 25%;
    }

    div.tablink:hover {
        background-color: #777;
    }

    div.tabcontent {
        color: white;
        display: none;
        padding: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #London {background-color:green;}
    #Tokyo {background-color:blue;}
    #Paris {background-color:Red;}
    #Oslo {background-color:orange;}

    button.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: #777;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Subject 1</a>
      <a href="#">Subject 2</a>
      <a href="#">Subject 3</a>
      <a href="#">Subject 4</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">

    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </div>

    <p><h2><b>Heading</p></h2></b>
    <p>Intro text......
    </p>

    <button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('London', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">One</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Tokyo', this, 'blue')">Two</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Paris', this, 'red')">Three</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openCity('Oslo', this, 'orange')">Four</button>

    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>One</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </P>

    <button class="accordion">1.1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">1.2</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">1.3</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p style="color:black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>
 </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Two</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p> 
     </div>

    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Three</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Oslo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Four</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <script>
    function openCity(cityName,elmnt,color) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

    }

    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    }



    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }

    </script>
         
    </body>
    </html>
```